# Daikon in place of pasta

Tags: substitutions, pasta

I remember seeing somewhere that one could use daikon in place of pasta, but I can't seem to find how one would prepare it.

Have you done this? If so, what should I be aware of when I try it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that someone was pulling your leg. You might be able to turn daikon into long, stiff, strands for decoration, but I don't think that any cooking process will yield something mistakable for pasta.

In fact, the recipe that the OP posted in an answer describes the situation as 'daikon *posing as* pasta.' The texture is not claimed to be even slightly similar; it's a visual pun.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find this recipe, I think this is where I got the idea.

http://us.dk.com/static/cs/us/11/features/morimoto/daikon.html

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but I've heard summer squash makes a good substitute as well. You could try the recipe [here](http://summertomato.com/better-than-pasta-subtitutes-summer-squash-noodle-recipe/).